# Get value from reflected method c#

Tags: c#, reflection

It is possible for me to get the value of a local variable from inside a method while it is being called.

The method I am invoking calls another method and passes it the value I want. Is there any way I can intercept that call or grab that value.

This is the idea behind my code:

```
namespace test
{
    class main
    {
        public static int Main(string [] args)
        {
            //This gives my the type of class I want since it is private. (this does work)
            Type classTypeIWant = typeof(otherNamespace.someClassInThatNameSpace).Assembly.GetTypes()
                            .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "ClassIWant");

            //This creates an instance of the class I want using the default constructor
            object classInstanceIWant = Activator.CreateInstance(classTypeIWant);

            //Invoke the method
            int resultINeed = classTypeIWant.GetMethod("MethodIWant")
                    .Invoke(classInstanceIWant, null));
        }
    }
}

namespace otherNamespace
{
    public class someClassInThatNameSpace{}

    private class classIWant
    {
        public classIWant
        {
            //stuff happens
        }

        public void BadMethod(int ruinLife)
        {
            //do stuff
            //ruin value I want
            return ruinedValue;
        }

        public int MethodIWant()
        {
            //this is the value I want to grab
            int valueIWant = 10;

            //but this method faults because of things I cannot change (I really cannot change this)
            int valueIDontWont = BadMethod(valueIWant);

            //it will not make it here because of BadMethod
            return valueIDontWant;
        }
    }
}
```

Intercepting the call to BadMethod would give the value I am looking for, but I don't know if it is possible to do that.

Comment: Can you inherit from *classIWant* ?

Comment: if `BadMethod` is not `virtual` you are out of luck... Decompiling/rewriting IL may be faster route...

Comment: if valueIWant is a constant value (i.e. 10) in this case, you cannot get that value. But if valueIWant is getting it's value from any other source e.g. class or textbox etc, you should be able to replicate the same to get the value. However that results in a duplicate code. The short answer is, No you cannot get a value from inside a function.

Comment: How do you know it has what you want?

Comment: Can you describe which pieces of code you have the power to change? I can think of a number of options, but they all involve changing different parts of code, and it's not obvious which changes are available to you.

Answer (score 0):

Is the class with BadMethod(int ruinLife) final?  And can you modify the signature of the BadMethod function to make it virtual?  If so, you could override that method with a dummy method that did nothing.  So:

```
public class newClass : classIWant
{
    public newClass() : base()
    {
    }

    public override void BadMethod(int ruinLife)
    {
        // Do Nothing
    }
}
```

Then just instantiate your class instead of the other class.  Note that this only works if you can make the BadMethod virtual, or if it is already virtual.  If not, this technique won't work, because using "new" instead of "override" won't work.

Comment: The problem with this is that the class is private so I can't just extend it. The method is not final though so is there some way I could use it?

Comment: If you can't change it from private to public, then there's not much you can do ( that I'm aware of. )  You could potentially change the class to internal instead of private if there is a concern about the class being visible to other assemblies, but that slightly complicates the inheritance because if your inheriting class is in another assembly you'd have to try something like adding [assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("newAssembly")] but I'm honestly not 100% sure that lets you actually inherit in another assembly.